# Can people have punctuation marks in their name?

Tags: grammar, nouns, proper-nouns

I am wondering if there is something that prevents punctuations in a person's name? I know apostrophes and hyphens are acceptable (i.e O'Reily, O'Brien, Mary-Ann, etc...)

I don't care how the name might be pronounced or how much they'd struggle with it; i'm wondering if it's possible/legal... Can someone have the name of

- M@rk!
- Th()mas
- $amuel
- "Larry"

for example...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about legal acceptability, which could vary depending on locale. It is not about learning English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about legal issues rather that the English language. Even with profound knowledge of English it would be impossible to answer the question, especially as the (original) names are used in non-english speaking countries too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define a name. Certainly, some artists have creatively spelt their names with characters to create a logo of sorts. It would seem extremely odd and potentially wrong to use that in a normal name, especially using quotes or exclamation marks.

Comment: This seems sort of relevant: http://xkcd.com/327/ :) You can call yourself whatever you'd like, but whether the courts in your locale will allow you to legally change your name to a particular mashup of characters is a matter for a lawyer.